# where does validates method reside in ActiveRecord::Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I understand that the documentation to the Rails 3.0.0 validates method is in [`ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods`](http://www.railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M003721)

I was wondering then, how a class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` has the validates method?

For example, it is common to use validates in such a way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  validates :name, :presence => true  
end
```

I looked at the class hierarchy and it seems like `SomeModelClass` extends `ActiveRecord::Base` extends `Object`

How is a method in `Active::Validations::ClassMethods` available to the model object that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Base calls `Base.class_eval { include Validation }` (and a bunch of other includes as well), which makes the methods inside ActiveRecord::Validations available as class macros.

Here's the actual line: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L306

You'll see this kind of thing all over Rails.

Comment: Link is broken. FIXED.